# How to spinbox allow only numeric

Tags: python, tkinter

I want that you can only enter numbers in the `spinbox` as in [this question](http://I%20want%20that%20you%20can%20only%20enter%20numbers%20in%20the%20spinbox%20as%20in%20this%20question%20they%20do%20it%20in%20html%20and%20js,%20what%20I%20have%20done%20is%20the%20following) they do it in `html` and `js`, what I have done is the following code

```
    self.infectedDefauld = tk.StringVar(self)
    self.infectedDefauld.set("1")

    self.populationSpin = tk.Spinbox(self.leftFrame, from_=1, to=100, width=5, bg=colorFive, fg=colorFour, textvariable=self.totalDefauld, bd=10, relief="flat")
    self.populationSpin.pack(side="top", pady=5)
    self.totalDefauld.trace(mode="w", callback=self.onValidationPopulation)



   def onValidationPopulation (self, varname, elementname, mode):
       m = re.search(r'\d+', self.populationSpin.get())
       if m: 
           self.totalDefauld.set(m.group(0))
       else:
           self.totalDefauld.set(0)
```

the problem is that when I write for example 2 it changes to 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spinbox -- like the Entry widget -- supports [input validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/7432). This is better than using a variable trace since a trace shouldn't be modifying the variable that is being traced. Plus, it can be used to prevent a character from being entered rather than having to remove a character after it has been entered.

Here's what it might look like in your code:

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.leftFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.leftFrame.pack(side="left", fill="y")

        self.populationSpin = tk.Spinbox(
            self.leftFrame, from_=1, to=100,
            width=5, bg=colorFive, fg=colorFour,
            bd=10, relief="flat",
            validate="key",
            validatecommand=(self.register(self._validate), "%P")
        )
        self.populationSpin.pack(side="top", pady=5)

    def _validate(self, P):
        return P.isdigit()
```